# create-react-app sample app problems

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create a sample create-react-app app:

```
create-react-app my-app
cd my-app/
npm start
```

Now it says to edit src/App.js, ok...
I want to use react component [fixed-data-table](https://facebook.github.io/fixed-data-table/)

Now, on that page is a "Basic Example" which gives lots of errors when I paste it into src/App.js - after some editing I get it down to:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Table, Column, Cell } from 'fixed-data-table';

// Table data as a list of array.
const rows = [
  ['a1', 'b1', 'c1'],
  ['a2', 'b2', 'c2'],
  ['a3', 'b3', 'c3'],
  // .... and more
];

// Render your table
ReactDOM.render(
  <Table
    rowHeight={50}
    rowsCount={rows.length}
    width={5000}
    height={5000}
    headerHeight={50}>
    <Column
      header={<Cell>Col 1</Cell>}
      cell={<Cell>Column 1 static content</Cell>}
      width={2000}
    />    
  </Table>,
  document.getElementById('example')
);
```

which gives me the following error:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are trying to render React in an element that doesn't exist, change `document.getElementById('example')` to `document.getElementById('root')`

**Update**
Your App.js file should use implement the `render()` function from the React component class:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Table, Column, Cell } from 'fixed-data-table';

// Table data as a list of array.
const rows = [
  ['a1', 'b1', 'c1'],
  ['a2', 'b2', 'c2'],
  ['a3', 'b3', 'c3'],
  // .... and more
];

// Render your table
class App extends Component {

  render () {
    return (<div>
    <div>Hello world</div>
    <Table
      rowHeight={50}
      rowsCount={rows.length}
      width={5000}
      height={5000}
      headerHeight={50}>
      <Column
        header={<Cell>Col 1</Cell>}
        cell={<Cell>Column 1 static content</Cell>}
        width={2000}
      />    
    </Table>

    </div>)
  }
}

export default App;
```

Then your index.js file just needs to render the `App` component

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I get: `React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.

Check your code at index.js:7.`

Comment: Thanks again. Hmm, now I'm not getting any errors but I'm also not seeing my table. Maybe that component is a dud.

Comment: Do you see `hello world`? Scroll down to the bottom of the page, you should see the contents.